# MongoDB query find

Tags: mongodb, find

Hello I am new in MongoDB.
I have 6 Objects like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5957a8eee0f3890011b64b99"),
    "name" : "Interní šetření spokojenosti zaměstnanců",
    "client" : ",
    "version" : "",
    "date" : ISODate(""),
    "ip" : "",
    "answers" : {
        "doporucil_produkt" : "ano",
        "vystupovani_firmy" : "ano",
        "vim_vizi" : "ne",
        "uvazuje_ozmene_proc_zustat" : "lepšie finančné ohodnotenie, zlepšenie tímovej práce",
        "uvazuje_ozmene_proc" : "vzdialenosť od bydliska",
        "uvazuje_ozmene" : "ano",
        "rozvoj_skoleni_chci" : "jazykový kurz",
        "rozvoj_skoleni" : "",
        "rozvoj_iniciativa" : "ano",
        "rozvoj_naslouchaji" : "ano",
        "rozvoj_vimco" : "ne",
        "rozvoj_rust_moznosti" : "5",
        "rozvoj_rust" : "[\"Aktivní participace na strategii firmy\",\"Zvyšování odbornosti\"]",
        "rozvoj_zustanu" : "ano",
        "spokojenostsnaplni" : "5",
        "rozumimnaplni" : "ano",
        "doporucilibyste" : "4",
        "ohodnoceni_prostredi_cozmenit" : "možnosť využitia bazénu a tenisových kurtov aj pre zamestnancov",
        "ohodnoceni_prostredi" : "dobrý kávovar, príjemné prostredie",
        "ohodnoceni_benefity_zbytecne_dalsi" : "",
        "ohodnoceni_benefity_chci_dalsi" : "lekárske prehliadky - v jeden deň\r\ndovolenka navyše",
        "ohodnoceni_benefity_dalsi" : "",
        "ohodnoceni_benefity" : "[\"benefits_homeoffice\",\"benefits_flexibleworkinghours\",\"benefits_car\"]",
        "ohodnoceni_benefity_spokojenost" : "ano",
        "ohodnoceni_proc_nepokojenost" : "",
        "ohodnoceni_spokojenost" : "ano",
        "ohodnoceni_proc_podhoceni" : "300€",
        "ohodnoceni_dle_vykonu" : "ne",
        "leadership_podpora_life" : "5",
        "leadership_podpora_work" : "4",
        "leadership_realnepozadavky" : "ano",
        "leadership_ocekavani" : "ano",
        "leadership_komunikace" : "4",
        "leadership_minus" : "viesť kolektív k tímovosti",
        "leadership_plus" : "priamosť, ústretovosť",
        "leadership_score" : "5",
        "leadership_komunikace_firma" : "3",
        "tym_spoluprace" : "4",
        "tym_offwork" : "ne",
        "leadership_komunikace_tym" : "3",
        "tym_kolegove" : "ne",
        "dreamjob" : "ne",
        "spokojenost" : "4",
        "workExperience" : "many",
        "quitYear" : "",
        "workedYears" : "0,6",
        "status" : "current",
        "position" : "manažér predaja",
        "department" : "obchod",
           },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need js function or query for seeing every values under the "answers" in one row
for example - obchod, manazer predaja, current,...

I used this :

```
db.getCollection('surveys').find().forEach(function(myDoc) { print( "user: " +myDoc.answers.department, myDoc.answers.position, myDoc.answers.status,
```

But I dont want to write all  "answers" subsequences.

Any sugestions?

thank you very much
Stuli

Comment: Hey I added an answer based on what I think you're asking for. You should make sure to format your data and code so it's easier to read. It makes it much easier to answer when things are formatted clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get all the keys of the object in an array. Then you can map over them to return the values. I think this function will do what you're looking for:

```
db.surveys.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
  var answers = Object.keys(doc.answers).map(function(e) { return ' ' + doc.answers[e] });
  print('user:' + answers);
})
```

Just so you know, you can use `Object.values` in the latest versions of JavaScript. But it's not available in MongoDB 3.4's JavaScript engine.

Comment: Hello Thank you very much, but this is not, what I am was looking for. I need functio that will show mi this data

Comment: Hello Thank you very much, but this is not, what I am was looking for. I need functio that will show me values of keys - for example ! "status" : "current" value and I wanted to see just "current" that mean all values of keys. No a keys of answers. Any idea?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake in the answer. Once you have the keys, you can use `doc.answers[e]` to get all the values inside the map. I've edited the answer. It should now work.